# Independent events. Throwing a die just once.

Tags: probability

If a die is thrown once and:

Event A: a one is obtained.

Event B: a two is obtained.

Are these events independent?

I find it confusing since I think independence relates when at least two throws are made.

Comment: Think about it:  Is it possible for both $A,B$ to happen?

Comment: The definition of independence is that$$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\cdot\mathbb{P}(B)$$Is this true in your case?

Comment: This exercise is meant to illustrate the difference between _independent_ and _disjoint_ events, something that many beginners confuse.

Comment: Lulu: no, they are mutually exclusive but this concept is different from independent events. Peter: not true, so,  are they dependent events? Amd: independence or dependence does not apply here?

Comment: @lulu as amd said, isn't what you asked pertaining to disjoint events and not independent events as the OP asked?

Comment: @Carlitos_30  Again, think about it:  can mutually exclusive events ever be independent?

Comment: @SohamKonar  See my last comment (addressed to Carlitos_30).

Comment: Yes, I see what you meant now sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intuitive way to think about the independence of events $A$ and $B$ is to ask whether knowing that $A$ happened changes your knowledge about the probability of $B$.

If you rolled a $1$ does that change the probability that you rolled a $2$?

Comment: The probability of rolling a 2 changed because is zero. Now, they are dependent, but Amd mentions they are disjoint, which suits better the concept or not?

Comment: @Carlitos_30 what do you mean by "changed because is 0"? Do you mean the probability of rolling a 2 changed to become 0 or do you mean that the probability of rolling a 2 changed by 0?

Comment: @Carlitos_30 Disjoint events are never independent. When one of them happens you know the other didn't. Before you rolled the probability of $1$ or $2$ were each $1/6$. After you rolled you know you saw a $1$. You no longer think the probability of $2$ _on this roll_ is $1/6$.

Comment: @Soham the former.

Comment: So, to clarify, you are saying that the probability of rolling a 2 became 0 after rolling a 1?

Comment: Not quite. The roll already happened (there's just one roll). Your _knowlege_ of the outcome changed when you learned that a $1$ was rolled. Imagine that you didn't see  the roll, but were told it was a $1$. Then you would be sure it wasn't at $2$, and would bet on that at any odds. If you'd been told the first roll was an even number you would bet on $2$ with probability $1/3$ rather than $1/6$.

Answer (score 2):

Formally, $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)=1/6*1/6 = 1/36 \neq 0$ so the events $A,B$ are not independent. This is just the mathematics. What about the intuition?

Knowledge about $A$ gives knowledge about $B$ and vice versa (i.e. if you know that $A$ happened, you know that $B$ cannot happen!).

More generally, if we have two events $A,B$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $0<\mathbb{P}(A), \mathbb{P}(B)< 1$, then $A$ and $B$ cannot be independent.

Comment: +1 for the intuition,  but your last statement is wrong unless you define *non-trivial* in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added how I defined non-trivial.

Comment: You’re welcome.  But the restriction “$<1$” isn’t necessary: two disjunct events are independent iff one of them has probability zero.

Answer (score 1):

Independence doesn't require more than one throw.

For example:

- the outcome is either $2,$ $4,$ or $6.$
- the outcome is etiher $1$ or $2.$

These events are independent.

But the events you've listed cannot be independent since each has probability $1/6$ and their intersection does not have probability $(1/6)^2.$